# iframe blocked by Chrome and Firefox in kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, windows-7, kiosk

I'm using Google Chrome and Firefox for multiple kiosk applications since 4 years.
I launch them either with the -kiosk parameter or I use them with a kiosk extension.
Today I need to present partners pages on this kiosk. Usage of an iFrame would be appropriate but I discovered that iFrame are blocked in kiosk mode by those browsers.
Did anyone experienced the same issue ?
Does anyone knows why ?
Thank you.